# How to fix error: "rzc generate exited with code 150"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My .NET SDK version 5.0.400 and trying to follow an ASP.NET Core tutorial to learn C# and ASP.NET in macOs. Whenever I try to build a controller scaffold, I've been getting the following error message:

> "rzc generate exited with code 150".

Clicking on it leads me to the following path:
`/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design/2.2.0/build/netstandard2.0/Microsfot.AspNetCor.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets`

```
<RazorGenerate
      Debug="$(_RazorDebugGenerateCodeTask)"
      DebugTool="$(_RazorDebugGenerateCodeTool)"
      ToolAssembly="$(_RazorToolAssembly)"
      UseServer="$(UseRazorBuildServer)"
      ForceServer="$(_RazorForceBuildServer)"
      PipeName="$(_RazorBuildServerPipeName)"
      Version="$(RazorLangVersion)"
      Configuration="@(ResolvedRazorConfiguration)"
      Extensions="@(ResolvedRazorExtension)"
      Sources="@(RazorGenerateWithTargetPath)"
      ProjectRoot="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
      TagHelperManifest="$(_RazorTagHelperOutputCache)" />
```

and this is my `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-jokesApp-EAACFB73-39CD-4EDF-9074-81C9C671FE8A</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" />
    <None Remove="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" />
    <None Remove="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="app.db" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" ExcludeFromSingleFile="true" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.15" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm not sure how to debug this or how to move forward from here.

Comment: Add your csproj too if that's possible.

Comment: I don't have a csproj file? Sorry if that sounds very obvious but I'm learning C# by following along with a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfEjDD8mWYg&t=1505s)

Comment: It's possible that it doesn't appear in Visual Studio, check in the Windows folder for the `.csproj`

Comment: I found and attached my ```.csproj``` file! :)